# XNA SpriteBatches- making them draw offset?

Tags: c#-4.0, xna, xna-4.0

Any suggestions for a good way to do this?

I want to be able to draw lots of 2D things in XNA- often in offset position. eg if something is in position (X,Y) then ideally I'd like to be able to pass it a modified SpriteBatch which, when Draw(X,Y) is called would take account of the offset and draw the thing at (X+OffsetX, Y+OffsetY).

I don't want to pass this offset to the children and have to deal with it separately in each child- that could screw up and would also screw up my interfaces!

Firstly I thought of having a Decorator to a SpriteBatch which if I call Decorator.Draw for something in position (X,Y) would route this to the original SpriteBatch as (X+offsetX, y+offsetY). But then I can't override the Draw methods in the SpriteBatch class, and even if I created my own "Decorator.DrawOffset", the Decorator seems to need "SpriteBatch.Begin()" called and stuff which seems to break... :(

I then thought of Extension Methods, but I think they'd need the offset passed to them as a variable each time draw() is called? Which still requires me to pass the offset down through the children...

Another option would be to draw the children to a RenderTarget (or whatever they are in XNA4) and then render this to the screen in an offset position... but that seems hideously inefficient?

Thanks for any comments!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should use a Transformation Matrix.

```
Matrix Transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(offsetX, offsetY, 0);

SpriteBatch.Begin(...,...,...., Transform);
```

Comment: Aha! That's a good way of doing it. Thanks very much!
Hmm, what should I do if I have already called SpriteBatch.Begin though? Is there a nicer way than:
SpriteBatch.End()
SpriteBatch.Begin(..., transform)
SpriteBatch.End()
SpriteBatch.Begin(go back to how it was to start with)
?

Comment: Same question here. The documentation states that it's better not to call Spritebatch.Begin and End more than once in a Draw loop! So how do you transform one object, but not all of them?